# Вернуть значение из промиса и экспортировать его, чтобы использовать в других модулях?

Tags: javascript

Использую динамический импорт модулей в модуле в зависимости от условий. Он возвращает промис (http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html) как мне , не создавая глобальный переменных, экспортировать отсюда  результат из промиса?

так, конечно не работает.

```
 if (условие) {
         import('./mymodule')
        .then(module => {

            if (module.value) {
               const res = module.value
                return res;
            }

        })

  } else {
          import('./mymodule2')
        .then(module => {

            if (module.value2) {
                const res = module.value2
                return res;
            }

        })
}

        export default res;
```

мне нужен результат в res

Comment: Кратко: вы не можете экспортировать результат из промиса, потому что его еще не существует в момент экспорта. Можно только экспортировать новый промис.

Comment: а как тогда экспортировать новый промис?

Comment: Посмотрите тот вопрос, на который я дал ссылку. Там в первом ответе написано как правильно один промис превращать в другой.

Comment: прочитал и не понял как применять для моей ситуации